# Can't add file when publishing to a channel. The modal window don't open up

Tags: channel-entries

Using version 2.5.3 and no third party add ons, just some of the natives.

I can upload files/images using the file manager without a problem. It's just when I try to publish in channel the modal pop up won't show when clicking.

I'm logged in as super admin.

I've tested this with different computers and with different browsers.

The upload folder should have proper settings.
Tested to sync folder.

BUT
A modal do show if there are no files in the directory, saying "You have no files.."

So the modal system seems to work, just not properly. I'd really appreciate some input on this.

Comment: Can you confirm (show us) that your upload directory paths are set up correctly?

Also, does this thread help? http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/225328/#1033346

Comment: what does the browser console tell you?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when I've had CP issues like this, a simple re-uploading of the original EE themes folder clears things up. There may be a corrupt file in there somewhere.

What happens after you do that?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I replaced the themes folder but the problem resists. 

Funny thing is when images folder is empty and I get the You have no files dialog, I can upload and choose i picture.